# Webpack: Does webpack.config.js get commited?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

Commiting to a repo now.  Does webpack.config.js get committed or is that generated on npm install?

Comment: Did you write it, or was it generated ?

Comment: is most of the case you need to commit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does webpack.config.js get committed[?]

Yes you should commit your build configuration files so that others can build your project using them. That includes webpack config files.

> or is that generated on npm install?

npm has nothing to do with webpack config generation. Running `npm install` will install your npm dependencies as defined in your `package.json`. You should add `webpack` as a dependency to your `package.json` by running `npm install webpack --dev`.

Running `npm install` might install a dependency which has a `webpack.config.js`, but this will not have been *generated* per se. The `node_modules` folder should be in your `.gitignore` file and as such you should not have to worry about accidentally committing files within `node_modules`.

Comment: even if the `webpack.config.js` folder is localted under the node_modules folder?   Right now, I see the file under `node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/webpack.config.js` .

Comment: @jjoan No, you should only commit _project files_, which mean files you have created or written yourself, not files within the `node_modules` folder which are external dependencies.

Comment: ok thank you!  I'm using Laravel Mix, which is a webpack wrapper for Laravel.  I guess webpack.config.js  got created upon npm install then?  I have a fill called `webpack.mix.js` , which is in the root directory and defines some Webpack build steps

Comment: @jjoan Aha - yes so you will want to commit the `webpack.mix.js` file in this instance.